# Jacobian Transformation help

Tags: statistics, multivariable-calculus

Let X1 and X2 ~ i.i.d N(0,σ^2)

Find the joint pdf of Y1:= X1^2 + X2^2, Y2:= X1/√(X1^2 + X2^2)

I tried using the Jacobian transformation:

X1 = √(Y1) * Y2 .......... X2 = Y1-√(Y1)*Y2

and then I took the derivative of dx1/dy1, dx1/dy2, dx2/dy1, dx2/dy2.

I got long determinant and now I am stuck. Please help?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3109614/321264

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did not get a very long determinant.

I denote $X,Y\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$. You want to find the density of the vector: $(U,V)=g(X,Y)= \left(X^2+Y^2,\frac{X}{\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}}\right)$.

The inverse of $g$ is:

$$g^{-1}(u,v) = \left( \sqrt{u} v, \pm \sqrt{u(1-v^2)}\right)$$
and the determinant of the Jacobian is:
$$\det J(g^{-1}(u,v)) = \mp \frac{1}{2\sqrt{u(1-v^2)}}.$$
So
$$|\det J(g^{-1}(u,v))| = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{u(1-v^2)}}.$$

Finally,
$$f_{U,V}(u,v) = f_{X,Y}(g^{-1}(u,v))|\det J(g^{-1}(u,v))|$$
where $f_{X,Y}$ is the joint density of $(X,Y)$ which you know well. Finally you only need to find the support region.