# Distribution of $Y_1$ and $Y_2$

Tags: probability, statistics

$X_1$ and $X_2$ be two independent Normal $(0,\sigma^2)$ random variables. Define $ Y_1=X_1^2 +X_2^2$ and $Y_2=\frac{X_1}{\sqrt{Y_1}}$ . Show that $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are independently distributed.
I tried to use transformation technique $(X_1,X_2) \to (Y_1,Y_2)$ but as the mapping is not bijective, I got confused.
Please help me out.

Comment: @user649261 Random variables may 'appear' to depend on each other but they may be independent. For example, $X_1+X_2$ and $X_1-X_2$ are independent if $X_1,X_2$ are i.i.d. $N(0,1)$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2017359/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3109614/321264

Answer (score 1):

The joint pdf of the $X_i$, multiplied by an infinitesimal element, is $$\frac{1}{2\pi\sigma^2}\exp-\frac{x_1^2+x_2^2}{2\sigma^2}dx_1dx_2=\frac{1}{4\pi\sigma^2}\exp-\frac{y_1}{2\sigma^2}dy_1d\theta,$$where the polar angle $\theta$ satisfies $Y_2=\cos\theta$. Since $Y_1,\,\Theta$ are independent (because the above result is of the form $g(y_1)dy_1\cdot h(\theta)d\theta$), so are $Y_1,\,Y_2$.

Comment: I don't know if the question was wrong but it was $\frac{X_1}{\sqrt{Y_1}}$

Comment: @user587126 As in $\frac{X_1}{\sqrt[4]{X_1^2+Y_1^2}}$? Yeah, that won't be independent of $Y_1$. In polar coordinates your variables are $Y_1=R,\,Y_2=\sqrt{R}\cos\theta$.

Comment: Sorry sorry i edited the problem

Comment: @user587126 Thanks; I've edited my answer. In the usual polar coordinates $Y_1=R^2$, so $r dr=\frac{1}{2}dy_1$. That should help you follow the revised calculation.

Comment: What will be the range of $\theta$?

Comment: @user587126 Note from the pdfs that $Y_1$ is $\operatorname{Exp}(\frac{1}{2\sigma^2})$-distributed while $\Theta$ is $U(0,\,2\pi)$-distributed.