# Suppose X and Y are independent N(0,1), How to calculate the joint density function of U=X^2+Y^2 and V=X/\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

And show that U and V are independent. I try to use Jacobian determinant, and calculate
$$J^{-1}=\frac{\partial(U,V)}{\partial(X,Y)}=\begin{vmatrix}2X & 2Y\\ \frac{Y^2}{(X^2+Y^2)\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}} &\frac{-X\cdot Y}{(X^2+Y^2)\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}}\end{vmatrix}=-\frac{2Y}{\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}}$$
I get stucked here, how to express the right-hand in terms of U and V?

Comment: $X=UV$ but $Y$ is not uniquely determined by $U$ and $V$.  So the transformation formula is not directly applicable.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I re-edit the question ,since i've made a mistake. But the problem is essentially the same.

Comment: Surely this has been answered before; https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3109614/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2017359/321264,